# Layout gravity bottom is not being applied

Tags: android, android-layout

The below is my `xml` file in which i want a `linearlayout` to be in bottom i.e. layout gravity bottom. But it is not working.

Even after looking all solutions given for this type of problem, i am not able to solve it. Please Help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
     
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" //----> not working
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTotalPrice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$23.00" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCheckout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
        android:text="@string/checkout"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the way i want.

[image]

Comment: `LinearLayout` with orientation vertical won't work that way

Comment: Then what should i do?

Comment: What is your expected output @HetviGandhi

Comment: I want that particular linear layout in bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="total"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTotalPrice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="$23.00" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCheckout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:text="@string/checkout"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This does not turn out to be my desired ouput!

Comment: @HetviGandhi can you share your expected result as image in question

Comment: I thought this is right answer as you expected @HetviGandhi

Answer (score 0):

Put Space layout between RecyclerView and LinearLayout

```
<Space
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

or use RelativeLayout instead of your main LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. and change this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tees"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTotalPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$23.00" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCheckout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    android:text="Hello" />
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What if i dont want to use relative layout in my xml file? Is there any other solution?

Comment: according your xml code only one solution to relative layout. if know then used contraintlayout it combined linear and relative layout.